# How to pass options to CloudinaryField in Django Model?

Tags: django, django-models, cloudinary

I am currently using Cloudinary with Django to store user profile pictures and would like to pass parameters to it store it in a folder and and overwrite the existing image instead of creating a new one.

In my user model:

```
picture = CloudinaryField('image')
```

This works as expected with Django Admin and forms. I would just like the ability to store it in the folder users/USERNAME/profile and when someone updates their picture to delete the old one.

Comment: See the explanation on [Django's upload documentation page](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/django_image_upload#django_forms_and_models), specifically he use of `CloudinaryFileField()` which accepts upload-option hash, incuding the `public_id` & `folder` parameters.

Comment: @NadavOfir [Overriding](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39906960/2996101) the ```upload_options``` method assures that the image will be transformed even if the model form is not rendered. For example, when a script tries to save the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**update**

The solution that worked in 2016 is no longer viable.
According to the [docs](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary#django), the following will work:

```
image = CloudinaryField(
    "Image",
    overwrite=True,
    resource_type="image",
    transformation={"quality": "auto:eco"},
    format="jpg",
)
```

The allowed params are listed [here](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/e2646b9933d234eea9dda3355025c3f082b1795e/cloudinary/utils.py#L68-L117) and [here](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/e2646b9933d234eea9dda3355025c3f082b1795e/cloudinary/uploader.py#L37-L42) in the code for version `1.17.0` or [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) in the docs.

For example, I was confused with the keyword `quality`. I was using it directly when using the API but in `CloudinaryField` is not allowed.

The proper way to define the quality of the uploaded photo is by setting:

`transformation={"quality": 80}`.

This is clarified in the [docs](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload_method) where it is explained that:

> Note that when using the SDK for a dynamically typed language, the
> transformation parameters can be specified directly without using this
> transformation parameter.

---

This worked perfectly:

```
from cloudinary.models import CloudinaryField as BaseCloudinaryField
from django.db import models


class CloudinaryField(BaseCloudinaryField):
    def upload_options(self, model_instance):
        return {
            'public_id': model_instance.name,
            'unique_filename': False,
            'overwrite': True,
            'resource_type': 'image',
            'tags': ['map', 'market-map'],
            'invalidate': True,
            'quality': 'auto:eco',
        }

class MarketMap(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=17)
    image = CloudinaryField()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also add these kind of options to the form field like so:

```
image = CloudinaryFileField(
    label='My image',
    options={
        'tags': "module, home",
        'format': 'jpg',
        'crop': 'limit',
        'width': 640
    },
    required=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me a while to realize -- and based on the questions I see in StackOverflow its not clear for others as well -- CloudinaryField and CloudinaryFileField appear similar but are different classes.  CloudinaryField is a Model class, whereas CloudinaryFileField is a Form class.  The options to specify a file path or tags are done at the FORM level with CloudinaryFileField ([See Image Upload API documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload))

```
from cloudinary.forms import CloudinaryFileField
# Note - cloudinary folders are specified at the FORM level and not in the MODEL
class EditPhotoForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Photo
    fields = ('name', 'description', 'image', 'slug')
    image = CloudinaryFileField(options={'folder' : 'media/photos/', 'tags': 'landscapes'})
```