# How to save CloudinaryField in a folder named by the user

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, cloudinary

I am trying to upload an image to cloudinary with a `CloudinaryField` in my `models.py`.
I want the image to be uploaded to a folder in cloudinary named in this format : `users/<username>/pictures/profile`.
so far I leart I can set `folder` and `public_id` of the field, but I cannot name it dynamically. for example I can pass a function in `upload_to` key in `ImageField` to create the image wherever i want. is there any way to do this with `CloudinaryField` ??
thanks ahead!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass options to CloudinaryField in Django Model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805137/how-to-pass-options-to-cloudinaryfield-in-django-model)

Comment: I tried the suggested answer. It dosen't work. whatever I set in the returned dictionary of the inherting class is ignored...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only solution I was able to come up with, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36805137/how-to-pass-options-to-cloudinaryfield-in-django-model) (which suggested answer did not work) is to override `pre_save` like so:

```
class CloudinaryField(CloudinaryField):
def upload_options(self, instance):
    return {
        'folder': "users/{0}/cats/{1}".format(instance.owner.username,instance.name),
        'public_id': 'profile',
        'overwrite': True,
        'resource_type': 'image',
        'quality': 'auto:eco',
    }
def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    self.options =  dict(list(self.options.items()) + list(self.upload_options(model_instance).items())) 
    return super().pre_save(model_instance, add)
```

I don't know if it's a good solution, but it's a working one...

Comment: Nice. You'd also need to return the object from the called `pre_save` method. If not your object won't have a CloudinaryResource attached to it, despite it being uploaded successfully

Comment: Cool. Same here. For future reference, [this is the original class](https://github.com/cloudinary/pycloudinary/blob/cae4ff1985f132e87ecaec9c382ffeb794162cc5/cloudinary/models.py#L105).

Answer (score 0):

In using the *CloudinaryField*, it can accept parameters as defined in the [Upload API documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#upload). The folder name (or prefix) can be provided as *folder=some/target/foldername*, while using both *use_filename=True* and *unique_filename=False* will set the *public_id* to use the filename of the asset. Otherwise, using a dynamic value can also be set as *public_id=some-dynamic-custom-value*.

For example:

```
           image = CloudinaryField('image',
                        public_id='dynamicpublicid',
                        use_filename=True,
                        unique_filename=False,
                        folder='users/username/pictures/profile')
```

Comment: trying to set it this way but i get the following error: `public_id (users/<django.db.models.fields.CharField>/pictures/profile/) is invalid.` seems Im trying to use a field that dosen't exist yet....

Comment: You can set the public_id with the filename of the asset (i.e., no / at the end, filename and extension is supported)